# Spacing in my blog's mobile view is non existent

Tags: wordpress, mobile, view, blogs, spacing

Please help me to fix the spacing on my blog's mobile view. The website is factbud.com. The desktop view is fine. Thank you in advance.

I did not try anything because I am afraid to mess the whole website. Please help me fix the problem. Very much appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this CSS in your active theme style.css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   body .entry-content > p {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
   }
}
```

Comment: where exactly do i place it?

Comment: You can place at end of the active theme style.css file. here https://factbud.com/wp-content/themes/broadnews/style.css